# Doob's inequality application

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning, martingales

I'm working through an example of the application of Doob's inequality in Durrett:

> Let $X_m$ be a submartingale, and define $\bar{X}_n = \max\limits_{0 \leq m \leq n} X_m^+$.
>
> Let $\lambda > 0$, and define A = $\{\bar{X}_n \geq \lambda\}$. Then
>
> $\lambda P(A) \leq EX_nI_A \leq EX_n^+$.

The example uses this inequality to prove Komogorov's maximal inequality by:

> $S_n = \xi_1 + \ldots + \xi_n $, where the $\xi_m$ are independent and have $E\xi_m = 0$, $\sigma_m^2 = E\xi_m^2 < \infty$. Since $g(x) = x^2$ is convex, then $X_n = S_n^2$ is a submartingale and using $\lambda = x^2$ we have:
>
> $$P \left( \max\limits_{0 \leq m \leq n} |S_m| > x\right) \leq \frac{\operatorname{var}(S_n)}{x^2}.$$

I'm not following how this is achieved. It is clear to me that:

$P \left( \max\limits_{0 \leq m \leq n} (S_m^2)^+ > x^2\right) \leq \frac{ES_n^2I_A}{x^2}$

And that
$ES_n^2 = \operatorname{var}(S_n)$, but shouldn't the expectation of $S_n^2$ change on $A$?
I think this shows I am not fully appreciating the need for the definition of $A$ in Doob's inequality, although I can see how it is necessary in the proof.

Finally, are we just taking the square root within the probability to get

$$\{ \max\limits_{0 \leq m \leq n} (S_m^2)^+ > x^2 \} = \{ \max\limits_{0 \leq m \leq n} |S_m| > x \}.$$

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $E(S_n^2 I_A) \le E(S_n^2)$.
2. The answer to your last question is "yes."

Comment: Yikes, duh! This makes me realize I need to appreciate the flexibility of <= just a little more, ha.